# How to add a custom view in Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8

I want to add a custom view(image+textbloc+image) in to a StackPanel programmatically on run time.I ve heard of templates which can be defined in Standardstyles.xml but how do i get their reference in the code and add them to stack panel.

I am new to Windows 8 (from iPhone) and in terms of iOS i basically want to add a custom view object as subview to a parent.

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a User Control (I think the equivalent to an iOS custom view object?). If you go to project > add new item and select user control, youll be presented with a screen similar to that of a normal page. You can design you control there and then use it in the project.

To add your User Control to a stack panel during runtime you can do something like

```
stackpanel_name.Children.Add(instance_of_User_Control);
```